# Returning a bare JSON-string

Tags: wcf, http

I got a web-service and want to return this "string" as a bare string,  without the extra serialization by WCF, because it's already serialized.How do I do it?

```
    [OperationContract]
    [FaultContract(typeof(Exception))]
    [WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
            RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    string Get_Json();
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution for this on [this page](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/636f1b89-f538-4486-bd07-069c64985a26). The following should work:

```
[OperationContract]
public Stream Get_Json() {
    return new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("This is a string"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add a servic/operation behavior that overrides the serializer.. and do nothing in it... just return the result as is

Answer (score 0):

A much better and cleaner solution seems to be this well documented and cleanly designed project https://github.com/mikeobrien/WcfRestContrib which aims to plug some of the existing holes in the WCF REST solution space.  This package is available also through NuGet with:

```
PM> Install-Package wcfrestcontrib
```